# icCube OutOfMemoryError

Tags: iccube

I'm using the icCube community version and trying to build a cube against Redshift, however, about 15 minutes into processing, I get the error below. Is this based on some restriction of the community version or something else?

thanks,
John

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at crazydev.iccube.builder.model.builders.facts.OlapBuilderBaseFactBuilder.resolveMembers(SourceFile:323) at crazydev.iccube.builder.model.builders.facts.OlapBuilderFactBuilder.onNewRow(SourceFile:136) at crazydev.iccube.builder.model.impl.table.OlapBuilderDataTableListeners.fireTableNewRow(SourceFile:125)

...

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you have reached the amount of memory available. The community edition has a memory limit ([www](http://www.iccube.com/edition-comparison/)). Please upgrade to an enterprise license or contact icCube for an evaluation license.

icCube has some documentation on memory, feel free to check how to increase memory - [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/jre_options.php) -  and how you can reduce memory footprint - [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/ram.php). Both are features available only in the Enterprise version.